# Increase the VIM window size on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

Is there a command to increase the size of the Vim Command window on the window machine?
Note: I do not need to set the start up size in the vimrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the VIM icon on the left top of the command window, select Properties, then Layout, and then change the Window Size for width and height

Or even better while in the editor use

- :set lines=40
- :set columns=80

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea what is Vim "command window". GVim in Windows is usually one window, and one window only.

If you wish to change the size of that window, you can change the number of lines and columns

```
set lines=100
set columns=100
```

for example.

If you're reffering to the number of lines you have available for writing commands

```
set cmdheight=2 (two is usually enough)
```